# On-click Placing Text into input boxes

Tags: javascript

On the page you click on a button(image) and text appears. When the text appears, you click on that text and I would like for it to appear in the input boxes.  For example, you click on image red.jpg, text will appear next to it that reads 'Fruit scents.' When you click on "Fruit Scents" I want it to appear in the intput boxes. I would like for this to happen in order from box 1 - box 3 and if the first box is full to go into the second. I'm not very good with using arrays so I'm not sure where to begin. This is all the code I have:

```
 <script>
   var current_obj='';
   function showLinks(objID) {
   var obj=document.getElementById(objID); if (current_obj.style) {
   current_obj.style.display='none'; }
   obj.style.display='block';
   current_obj=obj; }
</script>

<style type="text/css" media="all"> 
   .showhide_element {
    display: none; }
   html {
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-size:100% 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }

   #container{width:1950px;}
   #container div{float:left;width:300px;margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px}

   div#Contact {
background: #FFF;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 50px;
width: 1000px;
height:800px;
border-radius:25px;
-moz-border-radius:25px;
}
div#Contact_Text {
background: yellow;
}
div.Contact_Button {
background: white;
height: 500px;
margin-top: 100px;
width: 96px;
border:2px dotted;
border-radius:25px;
-moz-border-radius:25px;
}
div.test {

align:right;
}
#container #Contact .Contact_Button {
color: #909090;
}


#FruitsMenu_info {



width:96px;
height:500px;
}


#FloralsMenu_info {



width:96px;
height:500px;
}
div.Contact_Button2{

background: white;
height: 500px;
margin-top: 100px;
width: 96px;
border:2px dotted;
border-radius:25px;
-moz-border-radius:25px;
}
div.Contact_Button3{

background: white;
height: 500px;
margin-top: 100px;
width: 96px;
border:2px dotted;
border-radius:25px;
-moz-border-radius:25px;
  }
   </style> 
   </head> 

   <body  bgcolor="#ade0fa">

   <div id="container">
   <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 5000; top: 24px; left: 22px;"><img                 

   src="customize.jpg" width="288" height="100" /></div>

   <div id="Contact"> 

   <div class="Contact_Button">
   <p align="center"><b> <font color:"#a6a6a6">Select a Scent Category</font></b></p>

   <a href="#" onClick="showLinks('FruitsMenu_info');return false;"><div 
   style="position:     

   absolute;width:134px; z-index: 5000; top: 200px; left: 120px;"><img src="red.jpg"  

   width="132" height="43" /> </div></a>


    <a href="#" onClick="showLinks('FloralsMenu_info');return false;"><div   
    style="position:  

   absolute;width:134px; z-index: 5000; top: 240px; left: 120px;"><img src="Florals.jpg" 

   width="132" height="43" /></div></a>

   </div>

   <div class="Contact_Button2">
   <p align="center"><b> <font color:"#a6a6a6F">Choose 3 Scents </font></b></p>

   <div style="z-index: 5000; top: 540px; left: 220px;"id="FruitsMenu_info"  

   class="showhide_element">
<p align="center"><font color:"#000000">Fruits Scents</font></p></div>

   <div style="z-index: 5000; top: 540px; left: 220px;"id="FloralsMenu_info" 
   class="showhide_element"><p align="center"><font color:"#000000">Floral Scents</font>
   </p></div>


</div>



<div class="Contact_Button3">
  <p align="center"><b> <font color:"#a6a6a6">Your Blend</font></b></p>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <input type="text" name="Scent 1" id="Scent 1" />
      <label for="Scent 1"></label>
      Scent 1 

      <input name="Scent 2" type="text" />
      Scent 2
      <input name="Scent 3" type="text" />
      Scnet 3 
    </form>

</div>

  </div>
  </div>
  </body> 
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pretty basic example I coded up for you.

Using .value and some other stuff...

```
input.value="herp derp";
```

[JSFIDDLE link to example](http://jsfiddle.net/VrMXE/1/)

Comment: Hi, once again thanks for the code. It was a great reference for my code. I am now having problems getting the text that appears after you click on the image to disappear after you click on the next image. Can the: function showtext(id){
document.getElementById(id +"Scent").innerHTML=id;
} be turned into a show and hide function?

Comment: @user2121982 Yes, it's possible, basically you'd get the current value of the input and then search for a one of the values and then if it exists, remove it, otherwise put it in there.

Comment: Hi thank you. I'm not sure how to do this using a function. I've been trying to modify simple hide and show functions and I sometimes get the results I want but not quite.

Comment: Thank you! I got the hide & show to work. I'm trying to modify the function you provided me above and make it so the text appears in 3 input boxes instead of 2, but since it's an if, then statement it's not working...Any suggest on how i should go about changing this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user2121982
if(){}
else if(){}
else{}

Answer (score 0):

Just run this code after your html in js tags. Since you are not using jQuery, we'll go heavy handed. This might be too much as it grabs all innerHTML of the any p tag on your page and populates your input.

```
function updateInput(i){
   document.getElementById('name_of_input_id').value = i.innerHTML;
}
  var pTags = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for(i=0; i < pTags.length; i++){
      pTags[i].onclick = function(){updateInput(this)};
    }
```